Are Artinian rings also Noetherian?
I know that if $R$ is commutative, then the answer is yes. However, what if the ring $R$ is not commutative (with unit)? Some sources say that the result still holds, while others suggest that the ring $R$ may require additional conditions to ensure the conclusion.

You need the ring to have a unit. This should be standard though, i.e. covered in any decent source on noncommutative rings.

I'm reading: Rings and Categories of Modules (Anderson F.W., Fuller K.R.) and the theorem stated that: Let R be a ring with J = J(R). Then R is left
artinian if and only if R is left noetherian, J is nilpotent, and R/J is semisimple.

The conditions: "J is nilpotent, and R/J is semisimple" is still require right?

Ah my mistake, I know know. Thank you.

The result to know has been linked as a dupe. But left Artinian does not imply right Noetherian: DaRT query

@NaMan Half the result you're citing says: if $R$ is left Artinian, it is also left Noetherian.  It is also satisfying the other two conditions, but what do they matter... they're not hypotheses for this implication.

We suppose that $R$ has a unit, so that every ideal is contained in a maximal ideal by Zorn's lemma, which is what makes the Jacobson radical work properly. If $R$ is Artinian with a unit, then the Jacobson radical $J=J(R)$ is nilpotent and $R/J$ is semisimple. So each radical layer $J^i/J^{i+1}$ is semisimple and Artinian, hence Noetherian. It then follows that $R$ is Noetherian.
